# Please identify this plant?

Tags: identification, trees, fruit-trees

I also saw this plant in a house in Florida. The fruit (if that’s what it is) is small, it’s the same diameter as a regular pencil.

Can anyone identify it? And is it edible?

This is what the inside of the fruit looks like:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that this is coffee, either arabica or robusta, but the berry stalks appear to be a bit long on this plant. The leaves are shiny and corrugated as expected. Normally coffee cherries are arranged in small whorls tightly clustered around the stem, this one seems to have loose clusters on a branching stalk; from Hortus III it might be Zanzibar coffee.

From the cherry contents we can see that there are two "seeds" which is consistent with Coffea cherries.

If you wash off a single cherry does it look like a round "bean" with a kind of wobbly lighter line down the length on one side?

Comment: yes, likely a coffee, the glossy leaves are a good id key along with the berries

Comment: Coffee tree pix: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=coffee+tree&t=ffsb&iax=images&ia=images